# Can not start Glassfish server

Tags: java, windows, glassfish

When I attempt to run my java web application project on Netbeans 8.02, I keep getting this error:

> # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>   #
>   #  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007fff49cf42ec, pid=2768, tid=0x0000000000002860
>   #
>   # JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_111-b14) (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
>   # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.111-b14 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
>   # Problematic frame:
>   # C  [chtbrkg.dll+0x242ec]
>   #
>   # Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
>   #
>   # An error report file with more information is saved as:
>   # C:\Users\ZOOM IT\Downloads\Compressed\java_ee_sdk-7u2\glassfish4
> \glassfish\domains\domain1\config\hs_err_pid2768.log
>   #
>   # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
>   #   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
>   # The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
>   # See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
>   # Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=192m; support was removed in 8.0

and [this dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L762z.png) a bit later. 
I am using windows 10.
java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)

[Cannot start GlassFish 4.1 from within Netbeans 8.0.1 Service area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26004517/cannot-start-glassfish-4-1-from-within-netbeans-8-0-1-service-area) This problem relates to occupied port,which certainly is not my case.

Comment: Have you set the path environment var? Also open the log file and see what it says.

Comment: Can you please direct me how to set the path enviroment variable?

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26004517/cannot-start-glassfish-4-1-from-within-netbeans-8-0-1-service-area

Comment: @MASh No sir,that is not my case I'm affraid.

Comment: This might help you https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/entappclient.htmlhttps://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/entappclient.html

Comment: Page Not Found :/

Comment: Well as Mike answered its problem with the dll file, but still I would like to know have you done [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672281/environment-variables-for-java-installation)?

Comment: Yes.I did that .And it didn,t help.The glassfish server wouldn't start even from asadmin. After getting rid of the dll it worked fine. Thank you anyway. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a problem with GlassFish. Java has failed due to a problem with this dll file: `chtbrkg.dll`. Looking around on the Internet, there is a [hint from a Minecraft forum that this is likely related to some kind of 3rd party software](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/support/unmodified-minecraft-client/2749138-error-problematic-frame-c-chtbrkg-dll-0x23bdc?comment=8) and there are quite a few pages which associate that DLL with malware.

Remove the DLL and try again.

Answer (score 0):

It does look like some virus chtbrkg.dll here is the details - greatis.com/blog/how-to/remove-uninstall-chtbrkg-dll-virus.h‌​tm
The issue has been verified here [Eclipse Mars 2 jvm crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41048838/eclipse-mars-2-jvm-crash/41049372#41049372)
Same has been reported on https://bugs.openjdk.java.net and closed as not an issue, here is the link https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8171850
Please uninstall virus from above mentioned approach and try.